# How to force renderscript version to fix lint error: GradleCompatible

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, lint

All the support libraries I use have version: 26.1.0, and even those that come from 3rd party dependencies are forced with resolutionStrategy to 26.1.0

In build.gradle I have:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion 26.0.3
renderscriptTargetApi 16
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

./gradlew app:lint gives me the following error:

> ../../build.gradle: All com.android.support libraries must use the
>   exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime
>   crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 26.0.3. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and
>   com.android.support:renderscript:26.0.3

Since renderscript doesn't come as a usual lib and it doesn't even show up in the dependency tree I couldn't enforce it using resolutionStrategy.

Is there a way to fix this (other than setting `lintOptions {warning 'GradleCompatible'}`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targetting SDK version 27, then, 
I'm assuming you are using Android Studio `3.0.1`

Firstly, update buildTools version to '27.0.3'. I think they have solved this issue in this release, as I am not getting such lint errors now:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    ...
}
```

and your `SupportLibrary` version to `27.0.2`

See if this helps.